# How to configure JVM options for Java SE elastic beanstalk container

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a CloudFormation template to set environment variables for my Java SE elastic beanstalk application. I want to configure "java.security.properties" parameter from my CloudFormation template. I tried using "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment" namespace with option name as "java.security.properties" and option value as "path/to/security/file". However it doesn't work. I couldn't find any resources on setting JVM options for Java SE image. Any help is appreciated on how to set JVM options using CloudFormation template in Java SE image.